# Yandex Reporting API v.1 data differs from console

Tags: yandex

I am very confused, because API generates daily data that does not match the console's one.

For example, here is a comparison for UTM Campaign 'week':

Console / API

- Visits: 51 / 161
- Users: 44 / 152
- BounceRate: 13,7 / 37.88

Here's the payload I'm using:

```
payload = {
    'dimensions': 'ym:s:UTMCampaign',  
    'date1': date1, 
    'date2': date2, 
    'filters': "",  
    'ids': id,  
    'accuracy': 'full',  
    'pretty': True
}

for key, value in ids.items():

    payload['metrics'] = f'ym:s:visits, ym:s:users, ym:s:robotPercentage, ym:s:bounceRate, ym:s:pageDepth, ym:s:avgVisitDurationSeconds, ym:s:ecommerceRevenue'
    r = requests.get('https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/v1/data',
                     params=payload, headers=header)

    data = json.loads(r.text)['data']
    for dic in data:
        for val in dic.values():
            lst.append(f'{dic}; date: {date1};')
```

Whenever I switch to robotless view or not, the data is still not the same.
Accuracy filter is set to 'full' as in console.
As I see through the dimensions and metrics [documentation](https://yandex.com/dev/metrika/doc/api2/api_v1/attrandmetr/dim_all.html), units of measure are the same

What can I do to reach the concurrence?